# My name does me injustice; I've not done any harm

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Don't take me so literal,
>   I never damaged the view.
>
> I've a number of friends
>   Well.... More than a few.
>
> My father was in insurance,
>   in a city of du Sable.
>
> He wasn't very tall, sure
>   But he did what he was meant
>
> A famous brother never sleeps
>   in a borough oft unable.
>
> He's intended to be the one
>   to whom charges should be sent.
>
> A new device was once created
>   A man named Otis paved the way
>
> To help you move around inside
>   You use it to this very day

Who am I?

Comment: Well I definitely get a lot of the hints, but not sure of the answer... gotta resort to google.

Comment: got it... posting now

Comment: Yeah, this puzzle took quite a bit of research to put together.  There are a LOT of websites out there with false information about these things.  Nearly everytime I double-checked a fact, it was false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> A skyscraper

Don't take me so literal,
I never damaged the view.

> You're not actually hurting the sky.

I've a number of friends 
Well.... More than a few.

> There are now tons of skyscrapers.

My father was in insurance, 
in a city of du Sable.

> The first skyscraper was [Home Insurance Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Insurance_Building) in [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baptiste_Point_du_Sable) which was founded by Jean Baptiste Point du Sable.

He wasn't very tall, sure
But he did what he was meant

> It wasn't very tall, but for it's time it was impressive and led the way for tall buildings.

A famous brother never sleeps 
in a borough oft unable.

> Famous people stay and work in skyscrapers.

He's intended to be the one 
to whom charges should be sent.

> @TrevorPowell credit on the lightning strikes the highest points.

A new device was once created
A man named Otis paved the way

> Otis elevators allowed for people to travel up and down floors quickly.

To help you move around inside
You use it to this very day

> Elevators are in just about every building that's 2 or more floors now.

Comment: I couldn't find the du Sable reference. Good job.

Comment: I'm just not sure on those 2 stanzas except maybe wealthy people live and work in skyscrapers?

Comment: "He's intended to be the one to whom charges should be sent" is probably a reference to lightning (an electric charge) tending to hit the tallest thing in an area?

Comment: Ah... nice catch @TrevorPowell

Comment: The building was originally designed as a lightning rod, too.

Comment: Do I get the green checkmark? XD

Comment: I'm debating.  You got the details right, first, but Hobo figured out the answer a full 7 minutes before you. =D

Comment: I was typing... There were no answers on here when I started typing... If he got it and deserves it w/e.  ;) Although looking at it, he just typed the answer and nothing else...

Comment: "A famous brother never sleeps in a borough oft unable."  is presumably referring to one of the skyscrapers in New York City ("The City That Doesn't Sleep", according to Sinatra's song).  The Empire State Building is most likely the one being referred to.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm having the trouble.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Yes, this is the correct interpretation. :)  Manhattan to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it could be

> a skyscraper

Because

Don't take me so literal,
I never damaged the view

> Doesn't literally scrape the sky.

I've a number of friends
Well.... More than a few.

> There are lots of them.

My father was in insurance,
in a city of du Sable.

He wasn't very tall, sure
But he did what he was meant

> The Home Insurance building in Chicago.

A famous brother never sleeps
in a borough oft unable.

He's intended to be the one
to whom charges should be sent.

> Probably the Port Authority in #4 World Trade Center

a new device was once created
A man named Otis paved the way

To help you move around inside
You use it to this very day

> Elevators!

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Good job.  I'm going to give this one to Daily for having a more thorough answer, first.  I hope my formatting edits helped.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. :-( I can't figure out the spoilers.

Comment: You rejected my edit that had the spoilers fixed for you....

Comment: I didn't mean to, I kept trying to fix it myself.

Comment: Ah, I see that it auto-rejected.  I tried again.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't know why yours works but mine doesn't. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37144/discussion-between-khale-kitha-and-internethobo).